# I need to copy files from appdata/local to C drive and overwrite them each time the program is run

Tags: python-3.x

I use a program which, sadly corrupts some saved files at random times.  To be helpful (although I am a novice at this) I am trying to make a Python program to basically backup those file from the AppData/local directory and put them in a folder on C.  I need this program to overwrite the previously copied files each time it is run.

I need to generalize the AppData/local because each person who uses this program would, in theory, have a different user directory preceding the AppData folder.

I've tried running some of my own attempts at a solution.
I will post the results.

```py
# Imports

import shutil
import os
import distutils
from distutils import dir_util

# Paths

# os.makedirs("C:/RevSaves-Backup")
path = '%LOCALAPPDATA%/Remnant'
backup_path = "C:/RevSaves-Backup"

# Procedures

print("The Very Basic Remnant Save Backup Utility")
print(" ")
print("Backing up the save source:")
print(path)
print(" ")
print("It is recommended you run this at regular intervals \nto ensure you have the latest saves up to date.")

distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(path, backup_path)
print("Backup completed.")
```

When I execute this via command prompt or PowerShell, I get the following message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RevSaveBkUp.py", line 28, in 
    distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(path, backup_path)
  File "C:\Users\candr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dir_util.py", line 124, in copy_tree
    "cannot copy tree '%s': not a directory" % src)
distutils.errors.DistutilsFileError: cannot copy tree '%LOCALAPPDATA%/Remnant': not a directory

I am having trouble "targeting" the system-specific local AppData folder.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of reading, I made the following solution if anyone else is trying to do something similar.  I do not know if this is the "best" or "right" way of doing things, however.

Here is how I targeted the AppData Local folder regardless of the user logged in:

```py
path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'AppData', 'Local')
```

Some explanations for anyone who is new like me:

- **os.path.join** basically connects folders together in the path.  For example, using the above code, join would "connect" AppData to Local and the "User Folder" (referenced in the code as '~'). The output would look like this: C:\Users\your_username\AppData\Local
- **os.path.expanduser** defines the user in question.  For example, "~" targets the current user logged in. It goes inside the () because this is how you tell "your code" who, to target.  If you wanted a specific user (if you had more than one) you could possibly use os.path.expanduser('Jane') I believe.

Keeping the notes above in reference, this method allowed me to define the variables I needed to and use them for the copy above, where I could not normally use the AppData directory as I wanted.

This was done by using the following code as an example:

```py
path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'AppData', 'Local')
backup_path = "C:/MyBackupFolder"
```

Finally we executed the copy with this:

```py
distutils.dir_util.copy_tree(path, backup_path)
```

The above copied The AppData information I needed to the backup folder.

I hope this helps everyone learn as I did, it came in quite handy.